# how to show 2 value in google pie chart in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

i creating pie chart in codeigniter. My problem is its show me only one value.i need StockValuebyCost and StockValuebyPrice both , according to my code its show me only one value StockValuebyCost only, help me how to show both StockValuebyCost and StockValuebyPrice.

**MYmodel**

```
   function getStock(){
    $this->db->select('sum(quantity * cost_price)As StockValuebyCost,
            sum(quantity * unit_price)As StockValuebyPrice');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_quantities', 'items.item_id = item_quantities.item_id');
        $this->db->where('deleted', 0);
       return $this->db->get()->result(); // Return the results in a array.
    }
```

**MY Controller**

```
function getdata() 
    { 
    $data = $this->home_model->getStock();
    $responce->cols[] = array( 
        "id" => "", 
        "label" => "Topping", 
        "pattern" => "", 
        "type" => "string" 
    ); 
    $responce->cols[] = array( 
        "id" => "", 
        "label" => "Total", 
        "pattern" => "", 
        "type" => "number" 
    ); 
    foreach($data as $cd) 
        { 
        $responce->rows[]["c"] = array( 
            array( 
                "v" => "StockValuebyCost", 
                "f" => null 
            ) , 
            array( 
                "v" => (int)$cd->StockValuebyCost, 
                "f" => null 
            )
        );

        }
    echo json_encode($responce); 
    }
```

**my view js**

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package. 
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}); 

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded. 
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 

function drawChart() { 
  var jsonData = $.ajax({ 
      url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/home/getdata' ?>", 
      dataType: "json", 
      async: false 
      }).responseText; 

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server. 
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData); 

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options. 
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
  chart.draw(data, {width: 700, height: 500}); 
}
```

[image]
help me how to show both value

Comment: can you update post with `jsonData` data which is coming as response

Comment: how i can? can you please explain

Comment: in want `jsonData` from function `drawChart()`.  use `console.log(jsonData)`  after `var jsonData =$.ajax({ ...})`.Hit F12 to see console log in your chrome browser.

Comment: actually im new in this field so i dont what should i do next. please in console its show me just one row,

Comment: is data is correct according to query in model backend. if correct post it I want to see

Comment: Error: Invalid JSON string: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [StockValuebyCost] => 4702700.00000
            [StockValuebyPrice] => 5037300.00000
        )

)
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Total","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"StockValuebyCost","f":null},{"v":4702700,"f":null}]}]}

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [TotalProduct] => 184.000 [StockValue] => 4700700.00000 [StockValuebyPrice] => 5034800.00000 ) )

Comment: {"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Total","pattern"
:"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"StockValuebyCost","f":null},{"v":4700700,"f":null}]}]}

Comment: have you see [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) see data array used by that example  and compare with your data. I think there is some problem in controller. better you make correct model query and return result as `result_array()` and simply do `echo $json_encode($data)` in controller

Comment: i did it same as you said but "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error